# ¿Cómo puedo implementar la función "uniform" para que me arroje números pares o impares?

Tags: python, random

**Tengo dos dudas y un problema.**

*Problema:*
Trato de hacer que la función `uniform` me arroje números pares o impares, pero al momento de expresar dentro del rango `uniform(1,10)` el valor par o impar `uniform(1,10, 2)` me arroja un error: `TypeError: uniform() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

*Fragmento de mi código:*

```
x,y=uniform(10,50,2), uniform(1,10,2)
    x1,y1=('{0:.{g1}f}'.format(x, g1=randint(1,2)), '{0:.{g2}f}'.format(y, g2=randint(1,2)))
```

*Duda 1:*
¿Cómo puedo corregir este problema?

Duda 2:
¿Por qué la función `randrange` permite introducir un tercer argumento dentro de un rango de dos argumentos y la función `uniform` no? Agradezco mucho su apoyo!

Comment: El comando uniform te devuelve un numero decimal entre dos numeros. Los numeros pares e impares no pueden ser decimales, asi que te recomendaria que uses randrange.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entiendo que mi pregunta parece irracional, pero todos los días se aprende algo. Saludos!